# Labels in xtick with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am using Pgfplots to make a very simple graph. I already have the code below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=-10.5,
  xmax=10.5,
  ymin=-10.5,
  ymax=10.5]
\addplot [mark=none,domain=-4:4] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I need is to be able to use symbols other than numbers in the axes. So, instead of 1 2 3 4... I would like to have, for instance, + +  _ _ + + or other symbols for each point in the axes. How can I do that? I hope my question is clear!

Comment: Do you mean something like `xticklabels={$-$, $-$, $-$, $-$, $-$, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$}`?

Comment: Yes, I meant that. I used that but then I got only 4 points in the x axis. Then I added your suggestion after `xtick={-5,-4,...,5},` and it worked. Do you know how to add those same symbols to the diagonal axis?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: @Eduardo.D: With "diagonal axis", do you mean the plot you added using `\addplot ...`?

Comment: @Jake: Yes, I mean that plot. I just thought that I would use that because I could not get the extra axis (z).

Comment: @Claudio: Thanks! Struggling with a small plot here. First question and excited about my new account!

Comment: If you want to do a 3D plot, use `\addplot3` and take a look at Section 4.5 of the `pgfplots` manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you'd be better served with a "real" 3D axis. Here's a small example that shows how to create one (the key point is that you need an `\addplot3` command with at least one coordinate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale=1.5,
    x={(1,0)}, y={(0.6,0.4)}, z={(0,1)},
    axis lines=middle, 
    axis equal image,
    xmin=-4.5, xmax=4.5,
    ymin=-4.5, ymax=4.5,
    zmin=-4.5, zmax=4.5,
    xtick={-5,...,5}, xticklabels={$-$, $-$, $-$, $-$, $-$,, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$},
    ytick={-5,...,5}, yticklabels={$-$, $-$, $-$, $-$, $-$,, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$},
    ztick={-5,...,5}, zticklabels={$-$, $-$, $-$, $-$, $-$,, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$, $+$},
    xticklabel style={anchor=north},
    yticklabel style={anchor=north west, inner sep=1pt},
    zticklabel style={anchor=east},
]
\addplot3  [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is **exactly** what I had in mind! Thanks a lot Jake! Also thanks to @Psirus. I am a newbie but I will try to learn something from that long manual.

Comment: @Eduardo.D: You're welcome, I'm glad it helps. If you consider this question answered, you can mark it as such by clicking the tick mark next to the answer and upvoting it by clicking the upward-pointing triangle.