# Reducing space in pgfplots xtick label number format?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections} %% named intersections
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width= 400pt,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 5,
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 7,
  xtick = {0,1,...,7},
  scaled x ticks=real:2324823,
  xtick scale label code/.code={}, % this to not show extra scale label
]

\addplot [] coordinates {(0,0)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

... I'm getting xtick label formatting like this:

[image: test_pdf]

I would prefer less spacing between the numbers and the central dot - this is the previous image edited in Gimp to show my preference:

[image: test_pdf2]

Is this possible to do somehow - maybe through some settings for `/pgf/number format/sci`?

Comment: Instead of reducing the space (which gives inconsistent result), you can rotate them: `x tick label style={inner xsep=0pt,rotate=45,anchor=north east},`.

Comment: As @HarishKumar notes, reducing the space will give inconsistent results. But if you really need to do it, adding `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/sci generic={mantissa sep={\!\cdot\!},exponent={10^{#1}}}}` inside the `tikzpicture` environment will do the trick. Adjust the spacing/kerning commands around the `\cdot` to your liking.

Comment: Thanks @HarishKumar - in this case, I'd rather not rotate the labels (although I do that kind of stuff often). I found a "manual" way, posted it below - I don't think it looks that bad... Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @PaulGessler - that is exactly what I need; I've just learned a manual way to do that, and I've posted it below. Tried your suggestion and it automatizes it! If you don't mind posting that as answer, I will accept it; thanks again, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Based on my comment:

As @HarishKumar notes, reducing the space will give inconsistent results. Scientific notation in the text of your document will not look the same, and in general it's not a good idea to fiddle with TeX's spacing recommendations. The `\cdot` is spaced out because it is a binary operator.

But if you really need to do it, you may add
`[/pgf/number format/sci generic={mantissa sep={\!\cdot\!},exponent={10^{#1}}}]`
to the `tikzpicture` options, as shown in the complete code below.

Alternatively, you can use braces around `\cdot` to override TeX's default operator spacing:
`[/pgf/number format/sci generic={mantissa sep={{{\cdot}}},exponent={10^{#1}}}]`
The extra set of braces is required to prevent the keyval system from treating the braces as another nesting level.

You may, of course, further adjust the spacing/kerning commands around the `\cdot` to your liking.

### The code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

% Choose either one of the following two lines
%\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/number format/sci generic={mantissa sep={\!\cdot\!},exponent={10^{#1}}}]
\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/number format/sci generic={mantissa sep={{{\cdot}}},exponent={10^{#1}}}]
\begin{axis}[
  width= 400pt,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 5,
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 7,
  xtick = {0,1,...,7},
  scaled x ticks=real:2324823,
  xtick scale label code/.code={}, % this to not show extra scale label
]

\addplot [] coordinates {(0,0)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### The output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, thanks to these questions:

- [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing)
- [Removing spaces between "words" in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/851/removing-spaces-between-words-in-math-mode)
- [Labels in xtick with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97189/labels-in-xtick-with-pgfplots)

... at least I found a manual way to do it - by manually typing and overriding `xticklabels` at the end of the axis setup:

```
...
  xtick scale label code/.code={}, 
  xticklabels={$0$, $4.3{\cdot}\!10^{-7}$, $8.6{\cdot}\!10^{-7}$, $1.29{\cdot}\!10^{-6}$, $1.72{\cdot}\!10^{-6}$, $2.15{\cdot}\!10^{-6}$, $2.58{\cdot}\!10^{-6}$, $3.01{\cdot}\!10^{-6}$ },
]
...
```

... which results with:

[image: test_pdf]

... which doesn't look bad at all - but who wants to type this kind of stuff manually `:)`

So if there's some automatic way to wrap the `\cdot` and add a negative math skip `\!` after it, that would be great to know...

Comment: You could pass `\medmuskip=0em` to every tick label. Or (I think better) write the labels like `1.72`, `2.15`, `2.58`, etc. and on the side, a *general* `{}\cdot 10^{-6}`.

Comment: @sdaau: You can save yourself the typing work by using the approach Paul Gessler described in his comment: Calling `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/sci generic={mantissa sep={\!\cdot\!},exponent={10^{#1}}}}` somewhere before the `\begin{axis}`.

Comment: Thanks @Jake - I was hoping @PaulGessler would have posted his comment as an answer, so I can accept it `:)` ; thanks @Manuel for the tip too ... Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for the delay; my answer is there now! I wanted to do a bit of research to make a more comprehensive answer. `:-)`